# Find the time after 15 minutes of given time in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Find the time after 15 minutes of given time in  javascript
Example : given time is 2012-01-10 5:50  and I need to get like 2012-01-10 6:05

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will work for you

```
next = new Date ('Sun Jan 01 2012 5:45:10');
next.setMinutes (next.getMinutes() + 15 );
alert(next); //will result as Tue Jan 01 2012 6:00:10
```